# Why are annotations creating white background space around plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, geopandas

I wanted to understand why when I annotate the plot it creates a white space around the plot, and how I can remove it.

I have tried the bbox_inches when saving the image and nothing changes. I have tried the subplots_adjust and it adjusts the size of the entire plot around including the white space. I have tried adjusting the margins to no improvement.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly as py
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import geopandas as gpd
import colour
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.colorbar import colorbar

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='seismic_r', norm=custom_cmap)
sm.set_array([])
divider1 = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax1 = divider1.append_axes("top", size = "5%", pad = "9%")
state2020_data[state2020_data['state'].isin(['ALASKA','HAWAII','DC']) == False].plot(column = 'democrat_margin',
cmap = 'seismic_r', linewidth = 2, edgecolor = '0.2', norm = custom_cmap, ax = ax1)
cb_ax1 = fig1.axes[1]
for idx, row in state2020_data.iterrows():
    ax1.annotate(text = row['state_po'], xy = row['coords'],
                horizontalalignment = 'center', fontsize = 6) 
cb1 = colorbar(sm, cax=cax1, orientation = 'horizontal')
cb_ax1.tick_params(labelsize = 12)
cb_ax1.set_title('Winning margin')
ax1.grid(False)
ax1.axis('tight')
ax1.set_axis_off()
```

Here is the image if I drop the annotation code:
[image: Image without text]

Here is the image when I include the annotation code:
[image: Image with text]

I'd be really grateful if someone could explain what's going on and how I can erase the additional space.

Thanks

Comment: Are you annotating ['ALASKA','HAWAII','DC'] ?

Comment: as above, you aren't plotting Alaska or Hawaii, but you are annotating them, so...

Comment: Thank you both! You were indeed correct. Definitely a case of looking at it for too long and not spotting it